# Type «sudo» is not known on line 1 of the sources list

Tags: software-installation, spotify

7I was trying to install Spotify on my fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64Bits, something went wrong, now I got the error message shown in the picture and cannot open the update manager.

[image: Error message in Spanish]

These are the steps that I followed:

1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
   ```
2. Add the Spotify repository

   ```
   echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
   ```
3. Update list of available packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install Spotify

   ```
   sudo apt-get install spotify-client
   ```

**This is the message shown in the terminal**

```
$ sudo apt update
N: Omitiendo fichero «sp» del directorio «/etc/apt/sources.list.d/», ya que no tiene extensión de nombre de fichero
E: Tipo «sudo» desconocido en la línea 1 de la lista de fuentes /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: No se pudieron leer las listas de fuentes.
```

Comment: We can see only a part of the report and in a screen-shot we cant use the sroll-bars! Please copy the text of the report, [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/894172/edit) your question and paste the text into it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the steps you followed to install Spotify. You can check what you did in terminal using `history`.

Comment: Can you also open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) type `sudo apt update`, (prompt your password when asked) and paste errors messages, if any ?

Comment: @mook765, I am trying to copy the text but it won't let me. I can paste another image trying to show the whole message.

Comment: @Zanna yes, sorry I am new. I just solved the problem!

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

This question already has a general answer

In this case, I just deleted the file by running the following comand on the terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```